# How to put matrix into array in one for-loop?

Tags: c#

I am trying to put the values of a matrix into an array in a specific order. The matrix is `2*length`, where the length is the length of the message chosen by the user divided by two. The array is the entire length.

I have attempted using a for-loop where the first two values of the matrix ([0, 0] and [1, 0]) are put in the array.

```
Int[,] result = new int[2, length/2];
String[] resultArray = new string[length];
tracker = 0;

while (tracker < length) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length/2; i++)
    {
        resultArray[2*i] = Convert.ToString(result[0, i]);    
        resultArray[(2*i)+1] = Convert.ToString(result[1, i]);              
    }
    tracker++;
}
```

When I run this code, I get the System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' error message. The second expression in the for-loop is highlited.

I can't seem to realize what I've done wrong. `(2*i)+1 when i=(length/2-1)` should equal `length-1`, right?

Comment: Why do you have outer `while` loop?

Comment: And what was `i` when the error was thrown (and, thus, what was `(2*i)+1`, compared to `length`?

Comment: You might try to create a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, and edit the question to include that. One thing that is important to note is that, unless you're specifically enforcing that `length` is even, `length == 2 * (length/2)` might not be true.

Comment: What is the value of `length`? If it's odd, then `length / 2` will not be correct when doing integer division (i.e. `5 / 2 = 2`). However, this would only result in the last item in `resultArray` to be `null`. Can you please post a working sample that reproduces the problem (the above sample works fine for me with lengths of `5` and `6`)?

Comment: Also, the `while` loop is redundant - you're just doing the same assignments over and over again. You only need the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

*Not a explicit answer*, but way more fault proof than your aproach: to iterate trough a square matrix you can use

```
    var y = i / d 
    var x = i % d
```

where `d` is the dimension of the array

```
int d = 2;
int length = d * d; // square matrix;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

    // iterate trough the array via column -> row by row (or horizontal)
    int y = i / d;
    int x = i % d; // => i mod 2 (remnant of division by 2)
    resultArray[i] = Convert.ToString(result[x, y]);    
}

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

    // iterate trough the array via row -> column by column (or vertical)
    int x = i / d;
    int y = i % d;
    resultArray[i] = Convert.ToString(result[x, y]);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually iterate over a matrix using LINQ. You just need to use `Cast<T>()` to get the right IEnumerable interface then use a simple Select. It'll iterate over the first dimension first and within that iterate over the second dimension.

If I set up test data like this:

```
int[,] result = new int[2, 5];
result[0,0] = 00;
result[0,1] = 01;
result[0,2] = 02;
result[0,3] = 03;
result[0,4] = 04;
result[1,0] = 10;
result[1,1] = 11;
result[1,2] = 12;
result[1,3] = 13;
result[1,4] = 14;
```

Then this statement:

```
var resultArray1 = result.Cast<int>().Select( n => n.ToString("00")).ToArray();
```

Will yield these results:

```
00
01
02  
03
04
10
11
12
13
14
```

If you wish to iterate over the second dimension first, you can write a short extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToSingleDimension<T>(this T[,] source)
{
    for (int i=0; i<=source.GetUpperBound(1); i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=source.GetUpperBound(0); j++)
        {
            yield return source[j,i];
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var resultArray2 = result.ToSingleDimension().Select( n => n.ToString("00")).ToArray();
```

Which will yield these results:

```
00
10
01
11
02
12
03
13
04
14
```

See the example on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cp9KYi).

Answer (score -1):

You can use **MathNet.Numerics** library with some LINQ to achieve what you want:

> PM > Install-Package MathNet.Numerics

```
var result = new double[2,4]
{
    { 1,2,3,4 },
    { 5,6,7,8 },
};

var resultArray = Matrix
    .Build
    .DenseOfArray(result)
    .ToRowArrays()
    .SelectMany(q => q.ToArray().Select(w => w.ToString()))
    .ToArray();
```

You can use `ToColumnArrays()` if your initial array has shape [4,2] rather than [2,4]

Comment: This is disproprtionally complex and overengineered based on the question, OP comes here with a failing for loop, i don't think a recommandation of an external library and mapping that matrix to arrays then adding sublinq queries is appropriate at all